# How can I make the spacing single and grid lines on a list? I have one list that is and another that is not?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How can I make the spacing single and grid lines on a list?  I have one list that is and another that is not?  The two views have the same shaded style.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce your problem in my own environment, you can try other browsers, such as chrome, etc.